# How do I make a Mikrotik hAP ac3 use the front panel LEDs to show throughput?

Tags: mikrotik-routeros

The available options in `system leds set type=` seem to include only the interface speed, wireless signal strength, wireless status, and other stuff that has nothing to do with throughput or system load.

How do I make the Mikrotik hAP ac3 show how much bandwidth is in use?

Answer (score 1):

In the CLI, set the LEDs up so that led1-5 are used only by individual LED groups:

```
/system leds print
/system leds set 0 leds=""
/system leds add type=off leds=led1
/system leds add type=off leds=led2
/system leds add type=off leds=led3
/system leds add type=off leds=led4
/system leds add type=off leds=led5
```

Now when you check the LEDs it should look something like this:

```
[admin@house] > /system leds print
Flags: * - DEFAULT
Columns: TYPE, LEDS
#   TYPE       LEDS
0 * off
1 * poe-fault  poe-led
2 * off        led1
3 * off        led2
4   off        led3
5   off        led4
6   off        led5
```

(that it adds more "default" entries seems to be a bug in routerOS 7.7)

Now add a script and edit it:

```
/system script add name=usage-leds
/system script edit usage-leds source
```

Put this in the editor:

```
/interface monitor-traffic ether1 once do={
    :local r (rx-bits-per-second / 1024);
    :if ($r > 0) do={ /system leds set [find leds=led1] type=on } \
        else={ /system leds set [find leds=led1] type=off };
    :if ($r >= 138240) do={ /system leds set [find leds=led2] type=on } \
        else={ /system leds set [find leds=led2] type=off };
    :if ($r >= 276480) do={ /system leds set [find leds=led3] type=on } \
        else={ /system leds set [find leds=led3] type=off };
    :if ($r >= 414720) do={ /system leds set [find leds=led4] type=on } \
        else={ /system leds set [find leds=led4] type=off };
    :if ($r >= 552960) do={ /system leds set [find leds=led5] type=on } \
        else={ /system leds set [find leds=led5] type=off };
}
```

The constants are in kbps, and can be set to your desired threshold.  These ones are even from "any traffic" for the first, in fractions up to 540mbps (540*1024) for full deflection.

Now schedule it to run:

```
system scheduler add disabled=no interval=1s name="load LEDs" on-event=usage-leds
```

Run a speedtest or something and watch the LEDs indicate usage.

Comment: Wow! Great self-answered question.